# Is it normal for a cat to eat kittens?

Tags: behavior, training

I don't want to go into the grisly details (horror-movie stuff if a human were involved). But one of our tomcats just ate the days-old kitten of another of our cats. Is this normal?

I remember reading about lions eating cubs to force a lioness into heat. Does this apply to house cats as well?

If it's really abnormal, what do we do with the offending tomcat? The only charitable theory I could think of is that the tomcat thought that maybe the kitten was, say, a rat? In disgust, I literally kicked the tomcat out of the house.